# Variable Use Fgets with a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, fgets

I'm trying to read in a grade (1-10) into an array called moduleGrades.

The `fgets(moduleGrades[i]-1, sizeof(moduleGrades), stdin);` causes an error, yet what i've typed is exactly what I need. I want to store 3 grades (if the number of modules entered was 3)

many thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

char name[30];
int moduleNumber;
char moduleGrades[2];


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{   //read name & module amount
    printf ("Please enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    printf ("How many Modules: ");
    scanf("%d", &moduleNumber);


    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= moduleNumber; i++)
    {
        printf ("Please enter module %d grade ", i);
        fgets(moduleGrades[i]-1, sizeof(moduleGrades), stdin);

    }


    printf("%d", moduleGrades[0]);
    printf("%d", moduleGrades[1]);
    printf("%d", moduleGrades[2]);

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: *"yet what i've typed is exactly what I need"* -- so you're not getting a warning about passing a wrong type to `fgets`? Furthermore, `moduleGrades[2]` in `printf("%d", moduleGrades[2]);` is out of bounds. And `%d` is not the right format specifier for `char`. If you enter something like `'A'` when you get `moduleGrades[0]`, then `printf("%d", moduleGrades[0]);` will not print `'A'`.

Comment: Read your warnings. They are the compilers way of telling you that you're not doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: the errors i get are `'function': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'` and `'fgets': different types for formal and actual parameter 1` Thats what i mean I know there is something wrong with the fgets line

Comment: *"I want to store 3 grades"* - Then why is `moduleGrades` only 2 in size?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print three chars, as indicated by your output, then your array must also be able to hold three chars:

```
char moduleGrades[2];
```

Also this loop here:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= moduleNumber; i++)
```

This isn't wrong in itself because you subtract the `1` you're off inside the loop, but I would do this and just put this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < moduleNumber; i++)
```

The `fgets` call inside the loop is wrong. You're giving it a `char` instead of a pointer to `char`. Instead of using `fgets`, I would just use `scanf` again:

```
scanf(" %c", &moduleGrades[i]);
```

When you print those `char` that you read in, you need to use the `%c` format specifier, too:

```
printf("%c", moduleGrades[0]);
```

This way it'll print the `char` that you read in earlier. For instance, if you pressed `A`, it will print `A`. With `%d` it will probably print `65`, but it's undefined behavior, so anything else than that might happen instead and there's no guarantee on what exactly will happen.